# How to make a print preview and print buttons for my html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi currently i'm working on a html form with some fields, what all I need is to get a print preview of that form with the filled answers and later it should be printed on clicking on a print button. Can any one please help me out with this, I would be very thankful to you if you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript print preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090692/javascript-print-preview)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example you can refer this. 
Html code :

```
    <html>
   <body  id="printarea">
        <table class="tble">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Student Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    John Sypon
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>
                       Student Rollnumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        R001
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Student Address
                </td>
                <td>
                    132 Kane Street Toledo OH 43612.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Print" class="btn" onclick="PrintDoc()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Print Preview" class="btn" onclick="PrintPreview()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And include this css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
```

now print.css file :

```
@media print /*--This is for Print--*/
{
    .btn
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .tble
    {
        background-color: #CD853F;
        border:1px solid green;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact
/*above line of codes will set the table background-color and change the border color when we give the print and preview (print preview only when we see on print preview via browser) command*/

    }
}
@media screen /*--This is for Print Preview Screen--*/
{
    .btn
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .tble
    {
        background-color: #CD853F;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
  }
```

and style.css

```
@media screen /*--This is for Screen--*/
{
    .btn
    {
        background-color: #AFAFAF;
        display: block;
    }
    .tble
    {
        background-color: #E5E5E5;
        border: 1px solid #CD853F;
    }
}
```

Now include this javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*--This JavaScript method for Print command--*/
    function PrintDoc() {
        var toPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=350,height=150,location=no,left=200px');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::Preview::</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">')
        popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
        popupWin.document.write('</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
/*--This JavaScript method for Print Preview command--*/
    function PrintPreview() {
        var toPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=350,height=150,location=no,left=200px');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::Print Preview::</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="screen"/></head><body">')
        popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
        popupWin.document.write('</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
</script>
```

I hope this answer help!!!

Comment: its works I have tried it in my local, tested and posted this answer. let me know if you have any concern on this

Comment: But I have a form with text fields and drop downs.... Will it work for that?? i mean can i get those filled data as a pdf?

Comment: ya it works for form also because you are viewing everything inside of body tag so whatever is inside body tag it is previewed and printed ...

Comment: Its working for a static data.... But i'm not able to get the data from the text fields or a drop down..... :(

Comment: ok then for dynamic preview of form data refer this link :   http://adrian-alexan.blogspot.in/2009/12/customizing-entities-print-preview-form.html

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    print();
});
```

For print preview you can try [Print and Print Preview separately using HTML, CSS and JavaScript](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/83e5fed0-9db4-4b35-b34b-cca8de153655/Print%20and%20Print%20Preview%20separately%20using%20HTML%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript)

Comment: it is for print na?? how can i get print preview?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript method window.print()