# Open print preview dialog programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating an invoice tool within Google Sheets. The way it works is that after all the data is entered, a script is running, creating a sheet with the actual layed-out invoice.

I know that there is a way to automatically export sheets as PDF (by calling the document url with the "export?exportFormat=pdf" argument). But I don't want to export directly, I just need the "Print" dialog (File->Print) to pop up automatically so the user can adjust the settings before printing. (I know, it's not a big deal to press cmd+P yourself, but having the dialog open automatically would streamline the whole process a bit).

Is there any way to do that? I haven't found anything helpful within the documentation.

Comment: Unlikely that Apps Script can call on browser-specific details. Perhaps if you're using a sidebar in your design, you could use client side JavaScript to achieve this (since that html is actually running in the user's browser, and not Google's servers

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do that with Google Apps Script services but you might do that by using client side code.

Related

- [JavaScript print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090692/1595451)