# How do I use Firebug with print-preview in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, print-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see the print media CSS in Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765349/how-to-see-the-print-media-css-in-firebug)

I'm working on a Plone website with plenty of `@import` and linked CSS and am trying to use the Web Developer Toolbar to show only the print css.

Unfortunately on this particular website the web developer toolbar's print css has way fewer styles than regular 'print preview', won't reset without opening the page again in a new tab, and seems generally broken. Wikipedia for example responds better to the same 'view only print css' option.

How can I use Firebug with a print-preview-esque presentation? Could I be expressing the printability of different CSS declarations in a more web developer toolbar compatible way?

Answer (score 6):

Found this, witch might help you out: http://neutroncreations.com/blog/easy-print-css-coding-using-firebug-and-web-developer-toolbar/

> ... By using Firefox with its two close friends; Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar (you’re all using these daily for front-end engineering anyway, right?), we can make working on a print stylesheet as simple as one for the screen. Observe.
>
> First, open your website in Firefox, then we’ll ask Web Developer Toolbar to render the page using your print rather than screen CSS by choosing CSS → Display CSS By Media Type → Print from the Web Developer Toolbar...

Comment: This doesn't work, web developer toolbar is POS as far as I can tell.